# Verifying Möbius Transformations using Hyperbolic Geometry

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Verify that every transformation from $$H = \left\{Tz = e^{i\theta} \frac{z-z_0}{1-z_0 z} \right\}$$ can be written as $Tz = \frac{az-b}{\bar{b}z+\bar{a}}$ with $|a|^2 - |b|^2 = 1$.

The book gives the hint that we need to use algebraic manipulation to convert the first equation to the second using $$a = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}i\theta}}{\sqrt{1-|z_0|^2}}.$$ But I've spent several hours using this manipulation with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: I hope my edit hasn't changed the meaning of anything in your post. (I have to say though, it's not clear to me what you mean by $H=\{W=Z\}$.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The only thing you missed (probably my mistake), is that the bar sign in the second equation goes to "a" and "b" and not "z". I'm not exactly computer code savvy haha. Hopefully someone can answer the question.

Comment: Ya, the book formatted the first equation kind of weird. But that's how it's written in the book.

Comment: Are all the signs and conjugations (or lack thereof) correct as written? Conversion from $$e^{i\theta}\frac{z-z_0}{1-\bar{z_0}z} \qquad\text{to}\qquad\frac{\phantom{-}az-b}{-\bar{b}z+\bar{a}}$$ is relatively straightforward. (Note the added conjugation in the first fraction, and the added negative in the second.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let us try your book's hint and some educated guess:

$$|b|^2=|a|^2-1=\frac1{1-|z_0|^2}-1=\frac{|z_0|^2}{1-|z_0|^2}$$

So we could try (the educated guess kicks in)

$$b:=\frac{z_0e^{i\theta/2}}{\sqrt{1-|z_0|^2}}$$

and then

$$\frac{az-b}{\overline bz+\overline a}=\frac{e^{i\theta/2}z-z_0e^{i\theta/2}}{\overline{z_0}ze^{-i\theta/2}+e^{-i\theta/2}}=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-z_0}{1+\overline {z_0}z}$$

Comment: I would thumb up your answer but I haven't the slightest clue how to.

Comment: Perhaps you still haven't enough reputation to thumb up. It's an option appearing as arrow up-arrow down just to the left of the beginning of the answer. Don't worry, though. After some time has ellapsed you may want to *accept* the question that seems better to you, and this can always be done by the quetion's poster.

Comment: Ok, I think it worked

Comment: Your final result doesn't match the OP's original. You have "$1+\overline{z_0}z$" in the denominator; OP has "$1-z_0 z$". That's why I asked OP to double-check signs and conjugations.

Comment: That seems to be a misprint or an omission by the OP, but let us see if (s)he addresses this doubt.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that the original question had a couple of typos, and that the task is to match
$$e^{i\theta}\frac{z-z_0}{1-\overline{z_0}z} \qquad \text{with}\qquad \frac{\phantom{-}a z-b}{-\overline{b}z+\overline{a}}$$

where the second fraction's nature as linear fractional transformation meshes better with the condition $1 = |a|^2-|b|^2 = a \overline{a}-(-b)\overline{(-b)}$. Even so, the strategy I describe would also be suitable to prove the version that @DonAntonio demonstrated.

We'll ignore the hint and dive right into the search for an $a$ and $b$ that make the second fraction match the first.

---

Let's write that second fraction's denominator so that it matches the first's better:
$$\frac{a z-b}{\overline{a}-\overline{b} z}$$

Now, consider: If we want to make that fraction look even more like the first fraction, we'd want the numerator's $z$ to have $1$ for a coefficient. That's easily accomplished by *forcibly* factoring-out an $a$:
$$\frac{a \; ( z - b/a )}{\overline{a}-\overline{b}z}$$
That worked so well that we should do the same thing in the denominator, to change its *constant* term to $1$, and see where that takes us:
$$\frac{\;a\;}{\;\overline{a}\;}\;\frac{z-b/a}{1-(\overline{b}/\overline{a})z}
=
\frac{\;a\;}{\;\overline{a}\;}\;\frac{z-b/a}{1-\overline{(b/a)}z} = \frac{a}{\;\overline{a}\;}\;\frac{z-c}{1-\overline{c}z} \qquad \text{where} \quad c := b/a$$

Recall that, if $a = |a| e^{i\alpha}$, then $\overline{a} = |a| e^{-i\alpha}$, so that $a/\overline{a} = e^{2i\alpha}$; we need only take 
$$\alpha = \theta/2$$
to get $a/\overline{a}$ to match the multiplied exponential of the original fraction. To complete the conversion of the fraction, we only need to replace $c$ with $z_0$, which we can do by setting
$$b = a z_0$$

At this stage, however, we haven't completely identified $a$, only its argument. To get its modulus, observe that $|b| = |a z_0| = |a||z_0|$. Now,
$$1=|a|^2-|b|^2= |a|^2 - |a|^2|z_0|^2 = |a|^2 \left( 1 - |z_0|^2 \right) \quad \implies \quad |a| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 - |z_0|^2}}$$

Consequently,
$$a = |a|e^{i\alpha} = \frac{e^{i\theta/2}}{\sqrt{1-|z_0|^2}} \qquad\qquad b = a z_0 = \frac{z_0 e^{i\theta/2}}{\sqrt{1-|z_0|^2}}$$